# Update consecutive rows in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to Update a successive number of rows in a Table?

For instance, An `Employee` table contains hundreds of rows.

I have to update the rows, simply from 71 - 85.

You can plainly consider above as ids or row numbers of the table.

Comment: Kindly post your table structure, some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RANK()`

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT RANK() OVER BY (ORDER BY IdField) AS Rnk,
           field1, field2
    FROM yourTable
)
UPDATE C
SET field1 = 'NewValue'
WHERE Rnk >= n
AND Rnk <= n+m
```

Just a sample data as you have not provided any data

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET foo = 'bar' 
WHERE id > 70 AND id < 86;
```

Comment: @walther - How it is wrong? with the given information you can't say

Comment: "You can plainly consider above as ids" If he has a primary key called ID. The query will work. 

If he does not he will need to use rank.

Comment: @NoDisplayName, what if there are ids that got deleted? There's not enough information. This updates only rows that have id higher than 70 or lower than 86, but that probably won't update rows 70-86. That's different. sqluser answered this correctly, as OP should use Rank() instead. Or provide more information...

Comment: @walther - so you cannot say this is wrong there is no enough information to say this answer is wrong

Comment: @NoDisplayName, if I have a requirement `I have to update the rows, simply from 71 - 85.`, then yes, it's wrong. OP is clearly talking about row numbers, not ids (even though he's obviously not sure what would be the difference, but there sure is).

Comment: @walther You think the AND operator results in an OR operation?

Comment: @M.Scherzer, you really want to argue about this now? No, I don't think that, as I obviously stated few characters later rows 70-86. It's past 3am where I live at the moment and English is not my primary language, but that doesn't change a thing. Your code DOES NOT select `rows` 71-85`, but rather `ids`, that are larger than 70 and lower 86. That's a huge difference! Also those results might not even be consecuitive. What if OP uses GUID? Or doesn't use autoincremented column? Or has deleted rows between?

Comment: You stated: "This updates only rows that have id higher than 70 or lower than 86" . So yeah moving along... if OP wants ROWS this will not work, but then he mentioned he also has an ID column. Either way sweet dreams.

Comment: `I have to update the rows, simply from 71 - 85`, `row numbers of the Table.`